# Problems of submitting MSIX file to Microsoft Store Developer Backend (Error of publisher display name)

Tags: msix

The PublisherDisplayName element in the app manifest of delipdf_3.2.0.0_x64__tptbnkcnb2spm_1.msix is XIAMEN BAISHENGTONG SOFTWARE TECHNOLOG CO.,LTD.", OU=it, O="XIAMEN BAISHENGTONG SOFTWARE TECHNOLOG CO.,LTD., which doesn't match your publisher display name: XIAMEN BAISHENGTONG SOFTWARE TECHNOLOG CO.,LTD.

We tried to package our existing desktop application using MSIX Packaging Tool and the display name generated automatically by extracting the information from our CERT certificate, and we can't modify the name nor the CERT certificate at the moment,

Anybody can help, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, when you publish an app in the store you no longer need to sign it with your certificate; the Microsoft Store will do it instead. Digital signing is only required when you test the app on your local machine or if you plan to distribute it outside the Microsoft Store.

When you publish the app in the store, you need to disable digital signing in Advanced Installer(or the MSIX Packaging Tool) and set the publisher ID in the project to the value from your Microsoft Developer account, i.e., CN=82A13EFD-FE37-4EFC-8BA4-1C3E9EFE5F23